# How to know if view is being animated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uikit

Is there a way to know if my custom implementation of `setFrame:` (or an other setter of an animatable property) is being called from an animation block i.e. it will be animated or just set directly?

Example:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)newFrame {
    [super setFrame:newFrame];
    BOOL willBeAnimated = ?????
    if (willBeAnimated) {
        // do something 
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

In the above setter `willBeAnimated` should be `YES` it is called like this:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 
                     animations:^{view.frame = someRect;}
                     completion:nil];
}
```

and `NO` in this case:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    view.frame = someRect;
}
```

`someMethod` here is a private method inside UIKit that I can't access or change, so I have to somehow determine this from the "outside".

Comment: Could you add animated:(BOOL) as a param to your implementation and if you want to call set frame you pass it whether it's being called inside an animation block?

Comment: @Mike Unfortunately setFrame is not called by me and I don't have access to that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to check the `animationKeys` of the `layer` of your `UIView` subclass right after changing the frame to see if it is being animated.

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)newFrame {
    [super setFrame:newFrame];
    BOOL willBeAnimated = [super.layer animationForKey:@"position"] ? YES : NO;
    if (willBeAnimated) {
        // do something 
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

You can also to check if there are any animations by using `animationsKeys` which in this case would just return `position`.

In addition, if you want to force a change to not be animated you can use `performWithoutAnimation:`

```
 [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
        [super setFrame:newFrame];
    }];
```

**EDIT**

Another tidbit I found by testing is that you can actually stop the animation if it is already in progress and instead making the change instantly by removing the animation from the layer and then using the above method instead.

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)newFrame {
    [super setFrame:newFrame];
    BOOL willBeAnimated = [super.layer animationForKey:@"position"] ? YES : NO;
    BOOL shouldBeAnimated = // decide if you want to cancel the animation
    if (willBeAnimated && !shouldBeAnimated) {
        [super removeAnimationForKey:@"position"];
        [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
             [super setFrame:newFrame];
        }];
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```